# Computing wedge product of two 1-forms.

Tags: riemann-surfaces, algebraic-curves, exterior-algebra

> Let $L$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\pi :\mathbb{C}\to X=\mathbb{C}/L$ be a quotient map. Show that the local formula $dz$ in every chart of $\mathbb{C}/L$ is a well-defined holomorphic 1-form on $\mathbb{C}/L$. Compute $\int\int_X dz\wedge d\bar{z}.$

Here is my idea:

Let $z=T(\omega)$ define a holomorphic mapping from the open set $V_1$ to $V_2$. Then $dz=T'(\omega)d\omega$ and $d\bar{z}=\overline{T'(\omega)}d\bar{\omega}$. I'm not sure how to show that the local formula $dz$ in every chart of $\mathbb{C}/L$ is a well-defined holomorphic 1-form on $\mathbb{C}/L$.

Also,
$\int\int_X dz\wedge d\bar{z}= \int\int_X T'(\omega)d\omega\wedge \overline{T'(\omega)}d\bar{\omega}= \int\int_X ||T'(\omega)||^2d\omega \wedge d\bar{\omega}$

Now I think I need to use Stoke's theorem to finish the above computation but not sure how to proceed.

Any suggestions/hints will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The lattice $L$ acts on the complex plane by addition. Since
$$
dz = d(z + \omega_{0})
$$
for every (fixed) complex number $\omega_{0}$, the $1$-form $dz$ is well-defined on the quotient.

Writing $z = x + iy$ with $x$ and $y$ real, we have $dz = dx + i\, dy$, $d\bar{z} = dx - i\, dy$, and
$$
dz \wedge d\bar{z} = (dx + i\, dy) \wedge (dx - i\, dy) = -2i\, dx \wedge dy,
$$
or $-2i$ times the Euclidean area element. Consequently, $\iint_{\mathbf{C}/L} dz \wedge d\bar{z}$ is $-2i$ times the Euclidean area of a fundamental parallelogram for $L$.

Comment: Dear Adrew, thanks for your answer. I would appreciate if you could explain why $\iint _{\mathbb{C}/L}dx\wedge dy$ is the area of a fundamental parallelogram for $L$.

Comment: If $R \subset \mathbf{C}$ is a fundamental parallelogram, it maps bijectively to $\mathbf{C}/L$ under the quotient map (modulo boundary identifications, but the image of the boundary has measure zero). Since the projection $\pi$ is a local isometry (because the lattice acts by isometries),$$\iint_{\mathbf{C}/L} dx \wedge dy = \iint_{\pi(R)} dx \wedge dy = \iint_{R} \pi^{*}(dx \wedge dy) = \operatorname{Area}(R).$$